# Get mathematica to represent spcific matrices in the answer

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have defined the matrices as below:

```
A={{1,0},{0,1}}

B={{0,1},{1,0}}
```

I want mathematica to convert

> {{1,2},{2,1}} to A+2B.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried? As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You can start with:

```
Solve[a A + b B == {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 1, b -> 2}}
> ```